# circuit for any second order system

Tags: transfer-function

What circuit, with a **single input** and a **single output**, has a **transfer function** that looks like this:
$$H(s)=\frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\omega_n \zeta s+\omega_n^2}$$ (second order system)?

Comment: Input and Output should be Vin and Vout

Comment: A second order filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2nd order low pass filter is this formula but it's not quite the standard formula because you have possibly missed out a 2x term for zeta - bottom line should be

\${}{s^2+2\omega_n \zeta s+\omega_n^2}\$